# jquery page opens, give the message automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery

if yes is selected, the message I want you out automatically.

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ahmetsadri/JvsP6/1/)

HTML

```
   <div class="open">
                <select name="menu" >
                <option value="" ></option>
                <option value="Yes" selected>Yes</option>
                <option value="No">No</option>
                </select>


<span style="display: none;" class="group3">Open<input type="text" name="open" value="Yes"></span>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.open').on('change', function () {
    var group3 = $(this).find('span');
    var indis = $(':selected', this).index();
    if (indis > 0) {
        indis -= 1;
        group3.hide().filter(':eq(' + indis + ')').fadeIn(300);
    } else {
        group3.hide();
    }
});
```

selection is made only when the message is currently involved

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/GAHx8/ hope this helps

Comment: Please explain briefly ..!

Comment: @Satpal please post your fiddle as an answer, that's what the OP wants I suppose!

Comment: When the page opens "yes" is selected, a message is opened automatically get

Answer (score 1):

*When the page opens "yes" is selected, a message is opened automatically get*

*HTML*

```
<select name="menu">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Yes" selected>Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
</select>
```

*jQuery Code*

```
$('.open select[name=menu]').on('change', function () { //Changed selector
    var group3 = $(this).next('span'); //Used next instead of find
    var indis = $(':selected', this).index();
    if (indis > 0) {
        indis -= 1;
        group3.hide().filter(':eq(' + indis + ')').fadeIn(300);
    } else {
        group3.hide();
    }
}).trigger('change'); //Here used .trigger() to execute event handler.
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4kR9z/)

Comment: When the page is opened. yes on the right side of the selected message does not come

Comment: @user3769880, http://jsfiddle.net/4kR9z/ old fiddle updated now